# PKIX path validation failed

Tags: java, ssl

I'm trying to generate end certs for a client in Java.  I'm getting an error when I try to authenticate with the cert I give back to the client.  The error is:

```
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
```

There is currently an existing openssl implementationthat generates the end cert with these extension fields:

```
#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: F4 67 78 E4 40 80 FB FA   43 F3 48 3D 37 66 AC E1  .gx.@...C.H=7f..
0010: 44 3B B5 F1                                        D;..
]
]

#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:false
  PathLen: undefined
]

#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  clientAuth
]

#4: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=false
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Non_repudiation
  Key_Encipherment
]

#5: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 8F A6 A3 23 82 C9 20 2D   16 3E 3B 8E B5 D6 E2 8F  ...#.. -.>;.....
0010: EF 85 12 4C                                        ...L
]
]
```

So I tried doing the same thing in my code in Java which looks like (the majority of the code is stuff I found online about BouncyCastle cert generation):

```
private static void createEndCert() throws Exception {
        X500PrivateCredential rootCredential = readRootCredentials();
        X500PrivateCredential interCredential = createIntermediateCredential(rootCredential.getPrivateKey(), rootCredential.getCertificate());
        X500PrivateCredential endCredential = createEndEntityCredential(interCredential.getPrivateKey(), interCredential.getCertificate());
        writePem(endCredential, "end.cert.pem");
    }
}

// need to use existing certs and keys 
private static X500PrivateCredential readRootCredentials() throws Exception {
    File privateKeyFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "mykey.pem");
    PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(new FileReader(privateKeyFile));
    Object privateKeyInfo = pemParser.readObject();
    JcaPEMKeyConverter converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().setProvider("BC");
    PrivateKey privateKey = converter.getPrivateKey((PrivateKeyInfo) privateKeyInfo);

    CertificateFactory certficateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "mycert.pem");
    X509Certificate cer = (X509Certificate) certficateFactory.generateCertificate(fileInputStream);

    return new X500PrivateCredential(cer, privateKey, ROOT_ALIAS);
}

public static X500PrivateCredential createIntermediateCredential(PrivateKey caKey, X509Certificate caCert) throws Exception {
    KeyPair interPair = generateRSAKeyPair(2048);
    X509Certificate interCert = buildIntermediateCert(interPair.getPublic(), caKey, caCert);

    return new X500PrivateCredential(interCert, interPair.getPrivate(), INTERMEDIATE_ALIAS);
}

public static X500PrivateCredential createEndEntityCredential(PrivateKey caKey, X509Certificate caCert) throws Exception {
    KeyPair endPair = generateRSAKeyPair(2048);
    X509Certificate endCert = buildEndEntityCert(endPair.getPublic(), caKey, caCert);

    return new X500PrivateCredential(endCert, endPair.getPrivate(), END_ENTITY_ALIAS);
}

public static X509Certificate buildIntermediateCert(PublicKey intKey, PrivateKey caKey, X509Certificate caCert) throws Exception {
    X509v3CertificateBuilder certBuilder = new JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder(
            caCert.getSubjectX500Principal(),
            BigInteger.valueOf(1),
            new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()),
            new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + VALIDITY_PERIOD),
            new X500Principal("CN=Test CA Certificate"),
            intKey);

    JcaX509ExtensionUtils extensionUtils = new JcaX509ExtensionUtils();

    certBuilder.addExtension(Extension.authorityKeyIdentifier, false, extensionUtils.createAuthorityKeyIdentifier(caCert))
            .addExtension(Extension.subjectKeyIdentifier, false, extensionUtils.createSubjectKeyIdentifier(intKey))
            .addExtension(Extension.basicConstraints, true, new BasicConstraints(0))
            .addExtension(Extension.keyUsage, true, new KeyUsage(KeyUsage.digitalSignature | KeyUsage.keyCertSign | KeyUsage.cRLSign));

    ContentSigner signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA1withRSA").setProvider("BC").build(caKey);

    return new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider("BC").getCertificate(certBuilder.build(signer));
}

public static X509Certificate buildEndEntityCert(PublicKey entityKey, PrivateKey caKey, X509Certificate caCert) throws Exception {
    X509v3CertificateBuilder certBuilder = new JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder(
            caCert.getSubjectX500Principal(),
            BigInteger.valueOf(1),
            new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()),
            new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + VALIDITY_PERIOD),
            new X500Principal("CN=Test End Entity Certificate"),
            entityKey);

    JcaX509ExtensionUtils extensionUtils = new JcaX509ExtensionUtils();

    certBuilder.addExtension(Extension.authorityKeyIdentifier, false, extensionUtils.createAuthorityKeyIdentifier(caCert))
            .addExtension(Extension.subjectKeyIdentifier, false, extensionUtils.createSubjectKeyIdentifier(entityKey))
            .addExtension(Extension.basicConstraints, true, new BasicConstraints(false))
            .addExtension(Extension.keyUsage, false, new KeyUsage(KeyUsage.digitalSignature | KeyUsage.keyEncipherment | KeyUsage.nonRepudiation))
            .addExtension(Extension.extendedKeyUsage, false, new ExtendedKeyUsage(KeyPurposeId.id_kp_clientAuth));

    ContentSigner signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA1withRSA").setProvider("BC").build(caKey);

    return new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider("BC").getCertificate(certBuilder.build(signer));
}

public static void writePEM(Object object, String filename) throws IOException {
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(filename);
    JcaPEMWriter jcaPEMWriter = null;
    try {
        jcaPEMWriter = new JcaPEMWriter(fileWriter);
        jcaPEMWriter.writeObject(object);
    } finally {
        jcaPEMWriter.close();
        fileWriter.close();
    }
}
```

and my extensions that are output look like:

```
#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 45 62 E9 13 ED 2E 3F 23   A7 A8 F1 B2 DC FE 47 5A  Eb....?#......GZ
0010: E3 5E 88 EE                                        .^..
]
[CN=ourcompany.com, OU=OurCompany]
SerialNumber: [    01]
]

#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:false
  PathLen: undefined
]

#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  clientAuth
]

#4: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=false
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Non_repudiation
  Key_Encipherment
]

#5: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 6F C2 81 A9 42 54 DF C2   44 1B 40 B3 A1 DD AF BD  o...BT..D.@.....
0010: 87 3D 69 0F                                        .=i.
]
]
```

I see in section #1, there is data in the cert I created in Java vs the one that exists in openssl does not have that data.  Is that any reason why my client cannot authenticate?  Or is there something wrong in the Java code to create the end credential.

Comment: Path validation failure doesn't necessarily mean there is anything wrong in the leaf cert and there isn't anything visibly wrong in your leaf cert. OTOH **your code apparently** creates a random intermediate CA and uses it to sign a leaf cert, outputs the leaf cert and key, and **discards the intermediate cert** (and CA). This makes it impossible for anybody ever to validate your leaf cert, because validating requires the intermediate cert and the intermediate cert is destroyed. The openssl implementation probably keeps the intermediate cert (and key) and makes it available.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 can u put that as the answer. That's what I needed. Once I saved off the int cert so the server all worked. Thanks.